# SQL if clause in a transaction with rollback

Tags: mysql, transactions

Why is this not working?

Question:
2. Create a transaction to enter a new tournament. This transaction will do the following steps:

a. Check to see whether tournament that has ID 20 and tourney location ‘Totem Lanes’ is
inserted into table ‘tournaments’ (1 point).

b. If there is a record, tournament that has ID 20, ‘2016-11-29’ Tourney Date, and ‘Totem
Lanes’ Tourney Location is entered into the table ‘tournament’ (1 point).

c. Rollback all changes in the end of the transaction (1 point).

CODE:

```
/* Question 2 */
START TRANSACTION;

IF EXISTS SELECT *
FROM Tournaments
WHERE TourneyID = 20 and TourneyLocation = 'Totem Lanes'
IF EXISTS SELECT *
FROM Tournaments
WHERE TourneyID = 20 and TourneyDate = '2016-11-29' and TourneyLocation = 'Totem Lanes';

ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: What is not working?  And where is the insert? And what is being rolledback?  In order to rollback something needs to be created, no?

Comment: Maybe I read the question wrong and it says my If statements are wrong

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of what you have said is that if a tournament record that has an ID of 20 and a tourney of location of 'Totem Lanes' exists in table tournaments, then insert a record that has an ID of 20 and a tourney of location of 'Totem Lanes' and a Tourney Date of '2016-11-29'. It sounds a little nonsensical, but the way I would do it would be:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;

INSERT INTO Tournaments(TourneyID, TourneyDate, TourneyLocation)
   SELECT 20, '2016-11-29', 'Totem Lanes' FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT * from Tournaments WHERE TourneyID = 20 AND TourneyLocation = 'Totem Lanes'
   )
;

ROLLBACK;
```

This is a way of of doing a conditional insert using a WHERE clause. The WHERE clause is on a SELECT statement, which must provide the values for the columns being inserted. In this case, since the values are constants, they are selected from the MySql dummy table DUAL.